# Changing os.getenv() value help (beginner)

Tags: python

```
token = "lkjaskdl1jsa53dlksq34ajdsadasd99qqq" # you would need the source code to change this

value = os.getenv(token)
```

When I release my program using getenv(), **users won't be able to see the sourcecode to be able to change the token "value". Using message input, how could I write code so they can enter their token?** (instead of them changing it in the sourcecode)

Answer (score 0):

Use dotenv instead.
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

example:

```
$ pip install "python-dotenv[cli]"
$ dotenv set USER=foo
$ dotenv set EMAIL=foo@example.org
$ dotenv list
USER=foo
EMAIL=foo@example.org
$ dotenv run -- python foo.py
```

Set token in the same way as shown here for email and user

Or...

```
     import os                                                        
     my_var = str(input("Enter your token"))
     os.environ['key']=my_var
     x = os.environ['key']
     print(x)
~
```

Comment: Can you fill in the blank for me? I feel stupid as hell

So, instead of:
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
token = "ASDKLASDSAKDaskdhdfkldhds"

Replace it with:
______________

Also, how would I incorporate a message input into that? If it's not too much of a hassle

Comment: laptop:~$ dotenv set token ASDKLASDSAKDaskdhdfkldhds

Comment: But that specific token was just an example, I need them to be able to enter their own token (there rest of the code will make sure it's legit, there's no preset token they should be replying with)

Comment: see os.environ example I have just added in first reply